# Automatically add `insertable = false, updatable = false` to Netbeans-generated entities

Tags: java, jpa, jakarta-ee, netbeans, entities

I am working on a Java EE project using Netbeans. I automatically generated the Entities and JPA Controllers using the database.

I want to now update the Database by adding more tables or updating existing ones. Problem I run into is that I have to re-generate all the Entities and JPA Controllers -- which I do not wish to as most of my entities are modified to include

```
insertable = false, updatable = false
```

in the `@Column` where the database uses `current_timestamp`. If I regenerate them, I'll have to modify all the entities again to include the `insertable = false, updatable = false`.

This is what I am trying to achieve after creation.

```
@Column(name = "CREATED_ON", insertable = false, updatable = false)
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
private Date createdOn;
```

Comment: Usually, setting the Hibernate's property `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto` to **update** should only update your schema where changes are detected, so it should solve your problem. Can you try this approach?

Comment: I am unable to find that property in my project

Comment: If so, please include the following line in your **persistence.xml** file:  `<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>`

Answer (score 0):

You need to do it in 2 steps, at each step you can select the objects to create from and if you select them properly you won't write over your existing classes:

1. Generate entities from database
2. Generate controllers from entity classes

When I generate entities from existing tables, you select which tables you want to create.  Simply do this and do not select the existing ones.  Right click the project and select **New->other->Persistence(category)->Entity Classes From Database** I get the following dialog:

[image]

Then, do the same thing except select **JPA Controller Classes from Entity Classes**

Comment: This doesn't answer the question of automatically adding `insertable = false, updatable = false` to the `current_timestamp` variable in the Entity